# Are home-made cardstock cards durable?

Tags: playing-cards, custom-game-pieces, party, cards-against-humanity

I'm planning to print out the localized version of Cards Against Humanity to play with some friends, and I'm researching the best cost-wise way to do it.

The original PDF suggests using 80lb cardstock and that's it. That's *couché 360g*, a gramature I've yet to find here in Brazil - the heaviest I've seen in printshops is 300g. I'm researching some places to make thin PVC cards, but that seems hard to find, probably expensive, and I'm considering it as a last resort.

Questions:

- how durable would a plain cardstock deck be, considering it's not even going to be shuffled? I'm thinking about they getting destroyed by handing them around, dirty / sweating hands, occasional dirty on the game table (as this is a party game)
- what kind of finishings I could use in plain cardstock to give them a longer life? I've seem laminating and plastifying services in printshops, but they're also quite expensive (adds at least 3.5x the cardstock print price). I'm also not looking for pure home-made solutions, as some I've seen in Instructables or BGG, as there's *heaps* of cards and that's going to take a lot of time to finish - but if that would be the only way to go, suggest away.
- how important is to have round corners in this case? Do square corners play a big role in card durability?
- how bigger would the deck get if I use light sleeves on it? Consider the original deck has 560 cards, and I would add more expansions to it later.

Comment: Dunno where you got your conversion; 80lb cover stock is 215 g/squareMeter, not 360.  It should be very easy to find.

Answer (score 1):

It is pretty common in other CCGs to play proxy cards. This is typically made up of a common card from the game being played, in a sleeve with a printed copy of the desired card, cut from plain paper and the same size as the other cards, placed in front of the proxy card.

You are correct to point out that the sleeves do make the cards, and subsequently the deck, thicker. I wouldn't bother with liner sleeves (the really thin ones). These are intended to protect cards placed into hard shells. I'd try to make it work with deck protector sleeves.